# Php PDO Mysql update gives no results

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a mysql database table currency_exchange with columns currency,xrate and time.

I have a json currency feed which is providing currency exchange rates as:

"AED": 3.67266,"AFN": 57.1294 etc..

I need to update the values in my database. My php code is as follows:

```
$phpArray = json_decode($jsonData, true);
$extime =  $phpArray['timestamp'];
$rates = $phpArray['rates'];
include_once 'connstring.inc.php';
$uptime = date("m-d-Y H:i:s"); 
if (isset($rates) && !empty($rates) )//if data set and not empty
{
  $conn->beginTransaction();
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `currency_exchange` set `currency` = :currency,  `xrate` = :exchangerate,`time` = :time");
  try
  { 
    foreach($rates as $key => $value) 
    {
      $stmt->execute(array(':currency' => $key, ':exchangerate' => $value, ':time' => $uptime));
    }    
    $conn->commit(); 
  }//end try
  catch(PDOException $e)
  {
    $conn->rollBack();     
  }    
}//end if
```

Currently my table is empty. I need to have a if empty insert else update code. How is that possible.

Requesting Help. Thanks in advance.

Update:

Checked for $rowcount in currency_exchange table. if ($rowcount > 0) update it else insert. Solved it..

Comment: SQL UPDATE means to alter rows already present in the DB/table. Use INSERT to add rows.. (reg: "Currently my table is empty.")

Comment: You can't be sure that there aren't errors: you've written code to swallow error messages!

Comment: Sorry i meant to how to add if empty insert or else update. I have removed error checking code

Comment: You'd have to check (SELECT) if the resp. key (row) is already present and UPDATE the row or else INSERT a new row.

Comment: I am unable to understand how to use WHERE NOT EXISTS  for multiple rows

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned your table is empty, for the first time you have to perform an "INSERT" query. An "Update" query is used to update existing data only.
 You have to replace

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `currency_exchange` set `currency` = :currency,  `xrate` = :exchangerate,`time` = :time");
```

with

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `currency_exchange` (`currency` ,`xrate`,`time`) VALUES (currency, exchangerate,time");
```

Comment: I need to check for condition that if no values insert else update

Comment: $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO currency_exchange (currency,xrate,time) VALUES (:currency, :exchangerate,:time");   also results in no insert ????

Comment: Checked for $rowcount in currency_exchange table. if ($rowcount > 0) update it else insert. Solved it..